# g++ crashes after consecutive calls

Tags: c++, g++, opencl, ld

I'm developing a tool that makes several calls to g++ in order to compile and execute different versions of an original C++ program. More or less, this calls are made inside a loop (it's not a real "loop", but the calls are made inside a function that is part of an iterative algorithm).

For short executions of the algorithm, everything goes smoothly and all the g++ calls finish correctly (I get the binaries ready for its execution). However, the longer the algorithm executions are, the more likely the tool is to crash.

This crashes are due to subsequents crashes of g++ calls, that instead of returning the expected compiled binaries, return the following errors:

```
Compiling test_oclopts_23_14_6_6000.cpp...
g++ -O3 -L/opt/AMDAPP/lib -lOpenCL -I/opt/AMDAPP/include test_oclopts_23_14_6_6000.cpp -o test_oclopts_23_14_6_6000
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've googled a bit about this error messages, but I don't understand how they can be applied to my problem: the supposedly missing libraries really are well installed in the system (former g++ calls went OK).

Any idea? Moreover, if you know a better way to compile C++ source code inside a C++ program instead of using system(), I'm accepting suggestions, :)

Thank you so much in advance,

Jorge.

Comment: Better way to compile C++ inside a program = libclang.

Comment: May it be disk IO issue?

Comment: Is your program running out of memory? Check memory leaks.

Comment: You may be running up against an open file limit; check `ulimit -n`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, I'll do a bit of research about these topics.

Comment: As for a "better way" to compile things, my build software uses fork()/execve() on Linux/MacOS, which is almost the same as system(), just easier to handle wrt to command line arguments and accessing I/O streams. Thus, nothing better, almost the same thing. For clang, I also run the command line tools as I found the libraries to be either unsuitable or insufficiently documented; can't tell which :-) Not really seeing how system() could cause any of the suggested problems, as it is a rather synchrounous call doing all the cleanups by itself before returning.

Comment: I've increased the limit to 2048 with `ulimit -n 2048` and everything went smooth, :)